# Anticommuting relation in $bc$ CFT

Tags: string-theory, conformal-field-theory

(skip disclaimer)

I have a question about conformal field theory in Polchinski's string theory vol 1 p. 61.
Given anticommuting fields $b$ and $c$ and the Laurent expansions
$$ b(z) = \sum_{m=-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{b_m}{z^{m+\lambda}}, \,\,\, c(z) =  \sum_{m=-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{c_m}{z^{m+1-\lambda}} \,\,\,  (2.7.16) $$

Assuming $\lambda$ is an integer.

It is said

> The OPE gives the anticommutators
>   $$ \{ b_m, c_n \} = \delta_{m,-n} \,\,\, (2.7.17) $$

I tried to vertify (2.7.17), but I think my approach uses too strong condition. Here is my derivation:

Consider Operator Product Expansion (OPE) (similar with (2.5.9))
$$ b(z_1) c(z_2) \sim \frac{1}{z_{12}}, \,\,\, c(z_2) b(z_1) \sim \frac{1}{z_{21}}  $$
where $z_{ij}=z_i - z_j \,\, (2.1.22)$.

Therefore (it is just the anticommuting properties) $$ \{ b(z_1), c(z_2) \} \sim 0 \,\,\, (3) $$

Plug in Laurent expansions for $b$ and $c$, (2.7.16), into (3), we have
$$  \{ b(z_1), c(z_2) \}  = \sum_{m=-\infty}^{\infty} \sum_{n =-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{ 1}{z_1^{m+\lambda}} \frac{1}{z_2^{n+1-\lambda}}  \{ b_m, c_n \} \,\,\,  (4) $$

Since I aim at vertify (2.7.17), simply plug in (2.7.17) into (4)
$$  \{ b(z_1), c(z_2) \} = \sum_{m=-\infty}^{\infty}  \frac{1}{z_2} \left( \frac{z_2}{z_1} \right)^{m+\lambda} = \sum_{m=0}^{\infty}  \frac{1}{z_2} \left( \frac{z_2}{z_1} \right)^{m} +\sum_{m=-\infty}^{0}  \frac{1}{z_2} \left( \frac{z_2}{z_1} \right)^{m} -\frac{1}{z_2} $$
$$= \sum_{m=0}^{\infty}  \frac{1}{z_2} \left( \frac{z_2}{z_1} \right)^{m}  +\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}  \frac{1}{z_2} \left( \frac{z_1}{z_2} \right)^{m} -\frac{1}{z_2} $$
Without lose of generality, assuming $z_1>z_2$, we have
$$  \{ b(z_1), c(z_2) \}  = \frac{1}{z_2} \frac{1}{1-\frac{z_2}{z_1}}+ \frac{1}{z_2}\frac{1}{1-\frac{z_1}{z_2}} - \frac{1}{z_2} =0 \,\,\,  (5) $$

But if I use $\{ b_m, c_n \} =0$, it could also give Eq. (3). How to derive (2.7.17) properly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One can derive the commutation relation directly from the OPE. Recall equation (2.6.14) in Polchinski. We first note
$$
b_m = \oint_C \frac{dz}{2\pi i} z^{m+\lambda-1} b(z),~~c_n = \oint_C \frac{dz}{2\pi i} z^{n-\lambda} c(z)
$$
We then have
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\{ b_m, c_n \} &= \oint_{C_2} \frac{dz_2}{2\pi i} \text{Res}_{z_1 \to z_2} z_1^{m+\lambda-1}z_2^{n-\lambda} b(z_1)c(z_2) \\
&= \oint_{C_2} \frac{dz_2}{2\pi i} \text{Res}_{z_1 \to z_2} \frac{ z_1^{m+\lambda-1}z_2^{n-\lambda}}{z_1-z_2} \\
&= \oint_{C_2} \frac{dz_2}{2\pi i} z_2^{m+n-1} \\
&= \delta_{m+n,0}
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Comment: (2.6.14) is for commuting operators, how to use it to describe anticommuting relation?

Comment: The proof is the same. Try and follow the procedure to rederive the relation for anticommuting operators. You will find that the LHS simply becomes an anticommutator $\{ b_m, c_n \}$ instead of $[b_m, c_n]$